# Jmeter thread early termination？

Tags: jmeter

Please help

Use 150 threads,set duraion 300s,but **some thread** early termination.

Why?

- Jmeter 5.2.1
- Java 8
- Linux,use Non-GUI

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the reason is in your [CSV Data Set Config setup](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), if you have:

- **Recycle on EOF** set to `false`

and

- **Stop thread on EOF** set to `true`

when the thread (virtual user) runs out of available data lines in the CSV file - it will be shut down.

If this is the case you should see entries like:

> End of file:your_file.csv detected for CSV DataSet:CSV Data Set Config configured with stopThread:true, recycle:false

in the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

If you can re-use the data more than once - change these "Recycle on EOF" to `true` and **Stop thread on EOF** to `false` and your threads should run for 5 minutes without issues.

More information: [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

Comment: Hello,I added the picture.My settings always this. My data only once,but the thread Finished one by one .thx.